# Defining a function in a macro: can't use qualified name as parameter

Tags: clojure

I want a macro to define functions that return the form they were called as, e.g. `(func 1 (a b))` returns `(func 1 (a b))`.  I also want to allow input verification for these functions to make sure I'm not introducing any bugs.  (These forms will later be evaluated, but that code hasn't been written yet.)

I keep getting this error, though.

```
(defmacro defecho
  "Echo function call after asserting a few things about the input"
  ([f] `(defecho ~f nil nil))
  ([f assertions] `(defecho ~f assertions nil))
  ([f assertions assert-failed-message]
   `(defn ~f [& body]                ; define a function
      ~(when-not (nil? assertions)   ; if given a function for input validation
         `(assert (~assertions body) ; define the function to assert this as true
                  ~assert-failed-message)) ; with a given error message
      (conj body (quote ~f)))))      ; return the (f ~@body) list

(defecho my-test
  #(< 2 (count %))
  "Must be greater than zero")
```

2. ```
   Unhandled clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
   Error compiling:
   /private/var/...228.clj:1:1
   Can't use qualified name as parameter: my-test/body
   ```
3. ```
   Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
   Can't use qualified name as parameter: my-test/body
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use qualified symbols as function parameters.  Observe that

```
`body
```

evaluates to `current-namespace/body`

In a syntax-quote, you can always unquote a non-syntactic quote to get an unqualified symbol:

```
`~'body
```

evaluates to `body`.  (Notice that unquoting here serves evaluation of the inner quoting itself).

However, in this case you should generate a symbol instead, because if a user uses the symbol `body` within e. g the code of `assert-failed-message` you don't want his binding of `body` to be shadowed with yours (observe that his code is evaluated when the generated function is actually called).

It is common practice to generate symbols for that purpose, either using `gensym` or a symbol ending with a hash, which syntax quote will expand to a gensym call..

```
`body#
```

evaluates to the (unqualified!) symbol `body__34343__auto__` where the number differs on each invocation and is guaranteed to be different each time.

Since you refer to body from within two different syntax quotes, I picked the `gensym` option in combination with `let` so that only one symbol is generated.

```
(defmacro defecho ; overloads stripped for brevity
  [f assertions assert-failed-message]
  (let [args-sym (gensym "body")] ; define a symbol for function arglist
    `(defn ~f [& ~args-sym]                ; define a function
       ~(when-not (nil? assertions)        ; if given a function for input validation
          `(assert (apply ~assertions ~args-sym) ; define the function to assert this as true
                   ~assert-failed-message)) ; with a given error message
       (conj ~args-sym (quote ~f)))))
```

Comment: You can also use the syntax `body#` to auto gensym the name.

Comment: @drnewman Since the example uses `body#` in two different syntax-quoting contexts, different symbols would be generated.

Comment: Leon Grapenthin, you're right, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

You can make your life a little simpler by using a proper function for the heavy lifting and use the macro only for the syntax sugar:

```
(defmacro defecho
  "Echo function call after asserting a few things about the input"
  ([f] `(defecho ~f nil nil))
  ([f assertions] `(defecho ~f assertions nil))
  ([f assertions assert-failed-message]
   `(def ~f (echo-function (quote ~f) ~assertions ~assert-failed-message))))

(defn echo-function [f assertion assert-failed-message]
  (fn [& body]
    (when assertion
      (assert (assertion body)
              assert-failed-message))
    (conj body f)))
```